# How do I create a table that updates in real time in Processing from data from Arduino?

Tags: java, c++, arduino, processing

I'm trying to create a (for now) simple recreation of a plane's control surfaces for my uni project. I'm using Arduino. One of my ideas was to creat an FCS page where I could see the current position of the servos in real time. I tried using the terminal which, for debugging was useful, but if I want to be able to properly read the data as I add more servos, it will be hard to read unless I make a table.

I've been trying to read online on how to use Processing to read data from Arduino which I haven't really been too successful with and even less with creating a table. I don't have much experience with GUI so this is kinda new to me.

Here is my Arduino code;

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Servo leftAir; // create servo for left airelon
Servo rightAir; // create servo for right airelon
Servo leftEl; // create servo for left elevator
Servo rightEl; // create servo for right elevator

// Arduino pin numbers
const int X_pin = 0; // analog pin connected to X output
const int Y_pin = 1; // analog pin connected to Y output

int Ypos;
int Xpos;

int leftAirPos;
int rightAirPos;
int leftStabPos;
int rightStabPos;

int AoA; // Variables not used yet
int spd; // ^^


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  leftAir.attach(9, 600, 2300);
  rightAir.attach(10, 600, 2300);
  leftEl.attach(11, 600, 2300);
  rightEl.attach(12, 600, 2300);

}

void loop() {

  Ypos = analogRead(Y_pin) - 512;
  Xpos = analogRead(X_pin) - 512;


  if (Ypos > 10 || Ypos < -10)  // Small deadzone
  {
    leftAir.write((Ypos / 5.12) * 0.2 + 90); // move left airelon to designated angle (currently 20 degrees either way)
    rightAir.write((Ypos / 5.12) * 0.2 + 90); // move right aileron to the same angle -- servo will be looking in opposite direction so aileron will move down when the other goes up (currently 20 degrees either way)
  }
  else {}

  // Moving elevator / horizontal stabilizers

  if (Xpos > 10 || Xpos < -10)
  {
    leftEl.write((Xpos / 5.12) * 0.2 + 90); // move left elevator (currently 20 degrees either way)
    rightEl.write(-(Xpos / 5.12) * 0.2 + 90); // move right elevator (currently 20 degrees either way)
  }
  else{}

  leftAirPos = leftAir.read() -90;
  leftStabPos = leftEl.read() -90;
  rightAirPos = rightAir.read() -90;
  rightStabPos = rightEl.read() -90;

  Serial.print(leftAirPos);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(leftStabPos);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print(rightAirPos);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(rightStabPos);
  Serial.print("\n");

}
```

The table would hopefully looks something like this:

```
               Left   Right
Ailerons       20      -15
Stabilators    12      12
Flaps          5       5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the table you want is to be displayed continuously on a monitor?  Can you edit your post to show a small example  of what you would like the _table_ to look like?

Comment: Added at the bottom of the post, I hope that helps in visualizing what my idea is.

Comment: It looks like you can use `sprintf` to create the format you want and store it in strings. Then use `Serial.print` to send the strings.

Comment: Then why don't you display the table? Like `Serial.print("                 Left      Right");` and then `Serial.print("Ailerons        "); Serial.print(aleftalierons); etc.`? No, arduino is not in C, it's C++.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've tried that but it just becomes impossible to read the data because it's printing all the time and flickering, if that makes sense. I would prefer to have it on a GUI where all the text remains stable in place and only the numbers change.

Comment: @DavidCullen I hadn't thought of that, that seems like a better and effective way to transmit the data and I could just split it in Processing. Now all I need to know is how I could use that data to create the table and hopefully represent it in some sort of GUI if possible. I'll try to keep on looking online if I can figure it out.

Comment: @LuisDelBarrio This seems like a pretty detailed example of how to use Arduino data to actually manipulate complicated graphics in Processing: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/najad/displaying-values-from-arduino-using-processing-1f02da

Comment: @DavidCullenThanks, I'll take a look at it tomorrow when I can.

Comment: `and flickering` Then just wait some time after printing once. Your eye will not see that many values so fast anyway. Or calculate an avarage from like 10(1000?) values and display the avarage -> less data to display, less flickering. `how I could use that data to create the table` It's typically done by specifycing the width, like `snprintf(buf, sizeof_buf, "%20s %-10s %-10s", " ", "Left", "Right");` etc.